# Google Cloud Build and App Engine enviroment variables

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I have a secret token on my App Engine `app.yaml`

```
env_variables:
  TOKEN: super-secret-token
```

And obviously this token is out of git. Using Google Cloud Build, how can I set this parameter `TOKEN` at build time or before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Secret Manager within Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/securing-builds/use-encrypted-secrets-credentials) to get the actual secret and replace the `super-secret-token` placeholder value in app.yaml prior to deploying your app to App Engine. That would look something like this:

```
steps:
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: [ '-c', "gcloud secrets versions access latest --secret=secret-name --format='get(payload.data)' | tr '_-' '/+' | base64 -d > decrypted-data.txt" ]
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  entrypoint: /bin/sh
  args:
  - '-c'
  - |
     sed "s/super-secret-token/g" $(cat decrypted-data.txt)
- name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: ['-c', 'gcloud config set app/cloud_build_timeout 1600 && gcloud app deploy']
timeout: '1600s'
```

Having said that, your secret token will still be available unencrypted in your App Engine's environment variable which is not optimal security-wise. Instead you may want to query Secret Manager from within your App Engine code directly. You'll find code samples to do so [here](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/samples/secretmanager-get-secret).

Comment: This is super ungly Haha!

Comment: I guess I should use Cloud Run, there I can edit directly the enviroment variables

Comment: hehe well this is quite common use case, for example in [this CD sample](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/gitops-cloud-build) to generate new manifest for GKE.

Comment: As per Cloud Run, it is indeed easier to handle environment variable than in App Engine although they are also unencrypted and you shouldn't store your secrets that way as documented in the _caution_ note [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/environment-variables)